# Simpana CommVault logs and Splunk

Tags: splunk, commvault

What is the best way to get CommVault log data into Splunk? I don't see a Splunk app developed for CommVault, and CommVault generates *a lot* of log data. It would be extremely beneficial to collect and manage it with Splunk.

Has anyone successfully done this?

Any ideas would be helpful!

Comment: If you have sample data from the log files, it would greatly aide being able to help :)

Answer (score -1):

Wow - just up my street! We use both and do exactly what you state - we simply use Splunk to grab the logs and then have some searches written that only show us the errors rather than the successes - works a treat, but you're right there's nothing specific for it.